# How to embed raw JavaScript containing template literals in ReScript?

Tags: template-literals, rescript

For example, the following ReScript does not compile:

```
%%raw(`
const s = 'world';
const msg = `Hello ${s}!`;
console.log(s);
`)
```

The ReScript compiler (10.0.1) errors out at the backtick before Hello:

```
Syntax error!

3 | const msg = `Hello ${s}!`;

consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' or a newline
```

Answer (score 0):

This is being [worked on](https://forum.rescript-lang.org/t/rfc-support-for-tagged-template-literals/3744), but you should be able to replace the outer backticks with double quotes:

```
%%raw("
const s = 'world';
const msg = `Hello ${s}!`;
console.log(msg);
")
```

```js
const s = 'world';
const msg = `Hello ${s}!`;
console.log(msg);
;

//Hello world!

export {
  
}
/*  Not a pure module */
```

playground: https://rescript-lang.org/try?code=KTBOEMHcAoCICgDGB7AdgZwC4AJ3YLzYDkkyoANgCZEDcSaW2AtugOYHYAGAEgKbnlk2ACQBvdAF8AhJzooMycrwB0g1tBasAlHVhagA